# How to extract data from .review file in python?

Tags: python, xml, tags

I have a data set in a .review format files. When I open it using notepad the data is:

```
<tag1>
<tag2>
something
</tag2>
<tag3>
something else
</tag3>
.....
......
</tag1>
```

format I want to extract the "something" to a list in python. How do I do that?

Comment: That looks like XML to me..

Comment: Use beautifulsoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ or lxml lxml.de

Comment: @MartijnPieters it seem too. But it is not a xml document. Hackaholic yeah just a string . Vincent thanks man

Comment: @Optimuskck: then give us more detail than just the sample you gave. What you have now is perfectly parseable as XML.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i convert it into xml document as you guys said and perfectly able to strip the parts i want. :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [elementtree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to do this or maby [minidom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Does this help you in some way?
i also agree with what @Hackaholic implied, do you only need the info between Tag2 or is it in general? since you wanted info to a list, you can just store it in an array.